# This method jboolean (JNICALL *ExceptionCheck) (JNIEnv *env) where is defined?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm interested in the definition of this method. But I've found only the declaration in the jni.h file.... There must be an implementation somewhere I guess! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `jni.h` file is standard across JVMs in the set of definitions it provides. The actual implementations come with your JVM and generally comes as a library, whose source code may or may not be available, depending on the vendor.